# How to load Stripe in a React test?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm testing a React component that uses Stripe, and I'm wondering how to structure the test? I see this error:

> Error: Please load Stripe.js (https://js.stripe.com/v3/) on this page to use react-stripe-elements. If Stripe.js isn't available yet (it's loading asynchronously, or you're using server-side rendering), see https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#advanced-integrations

The production code is pretty basic:

```js
<StripeProvider apiKey={config.stripeKey}>
    <MyCheckout />
</StripeProvider>
```

the test code is basic as well, but results in an error. The error doesn't occur when I just access the app in the broswer:

```js
  it('Should render the correct element', () => {
    let rendered = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Account />
      </Provider>)
    let elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(rendered)
    expect(elem.tagName.toLowerCase()).to.equal('div')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like their advanced guide answers this question, the part there they do this:

```js
  componentDidMount () {
    if (window.Stripe) {
      this.setState({stripe: window.Stripe(config.stripeKey)}) // eslint-disable-line new-cap
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#stripe-js').addEventListener('load', () => {
        this.setState({stripe: window.Stripe(config.stripeKey)}) // eslint-disable-line new-cap
      })
    }
  }
```

and in my test:

```js
  it('Should render the correct element', () => {
    window.Stripe = function () {}
    let rendered = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CartPage />
      </Provider>)
    let elem = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(rendered)
    expect(elem.tagName.toLowerCase()).to.equal('div')
  })
```

The test at least runs.